# Python - print between strings

Tags: python, bash, sed, awk

I am trying to figure out how to print everything that occurs between 2 strings.  The thing is, these pairs of strings occur multiple times on a single line.  So I need to be able to print each field within each set of pairs.

I have a file `api.txt` that lists multiple customers and their respective device inventories.  It looks something like this:

```
Customer [customerId=12000, customerName=Acme, Inc.]
DeviceDetail [baseProductId=router-100, cardDetail=[CardDetail [baseCardId=router-100NIC1, cardDescription=Router 100 NIC, cardSerial=100NIC1], CardDetail [baseCardId=router-100NIC2, cardDescription=Router 100 NIC, cardSerial=100NIC2]], deviceSerial=100PRIMARY, deviceDescription=Router 100 Base Model]
DeviceDetail [baseProductId=router-2500, cardDetail=[CardDetail [baseCardId=router-2500NIC1, cardDescription=Router 2500 NIC, cardSerial=2500NIC1], CardDetail [baseCardId=router-2500NIC2, cardDescription=Router 2500 NIC, cardSerial=2500NIC2]], deviceSerial=2500PRIMARY, deviceDescription=Router 2500 Base Model]
Customer [customerId=24000, customerName=Anvil LLC]
DeviceDetail [baseProductId=router-5000, cardDetail=[CardDetail [baseCardId=router-5000NIC1, cardDescription=Router 5000 NIC, cardSerial=5000NIC1], CardDetail [baseCardId=router-500NIC2, cardDescription=Router 5000 NIC, cardSerial=5000NIC2]], deviceSerial=5000PRIMARY, deviceDescription=Router 5000 Base Model]
DeviceDetail [baseProductId=router-7500, cardDetail=null, deviceSerial=7500PRIMARY, DeviceDescription=Router 7500 Base Model, No NIC]
```

The output of this should looks something like:

```
"12000","Acme, Inc.","router-100","100PRIMARY","Router 100 Base Model","Router 100 NIC","100NIC1","Router 100 NIC","100NIC2"
"12000","Acme, Inc.","router-2500","2500Primary","Router 2500 Base Model","Router 2500 NIC","2500NIC1","Router 2500 NIC","2500NIC2"
"24000","Anvil LLC","router-5000","5000PRIMARY","Router 5000 Base Model,"Router 5000 NIC","5000NIC1","Router 5000 NIC","5000NIC2"
```

Notice that the last DeviceDetail (`router-7500`) is omitted since the device had no child devices attached to it (`cardDetail=null`).

I understand how to use `awk` to set the field delimiters to `=` and `,` to capture everything that is between them (i.e. each field value resides between the equals and comma), but I'm not certain how to attain the results I'm looking for when multiple instances of the `CardDetail` data can appear an unknown number of times, or even not at all, on each line.

Something for consideration is that each instance of `Card Detail` is captured between `Card Detail` and a closed bracket (`]`), so that might assist in capturing each instance of `Card Detail` on each line, but not sure.

I'm also not married to `awk`.  Using `sed` or any other parsing program will work as well.  Basically, whatever works best.

Thanks in advance for any help offered!

Comment: any chance of reformatting the source into a sane format?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  The API from which this comes has no ability for output manipulation.  Either you get this or nothing at all. :-/

Answer (score 2):

When the processing gets too awkward to be done in awk/sed, it's time to use a more 'modern' scripting language, like perl, or ruby, or python. Something like this should get you started (perl):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $customerName;
my $customerId;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    if ($line =~ m{
            customerId=(?<customerId>.*?), 
            \ customerName=(?<customerName>.*)\]
        }x)
    {
            $customerId = $+{customerId};
            $customerName = $+{customerName};
    } elsif ($line =~ m{
                    baseProductId=(?<baseProductId>.*?),
                    \ cardDetail=\[.*baseCardId=(?<baseCardId>.*?),
                    \ cardDescription=(?<cardDescription>.*?),
                    .*deviceSerial=(?<deviceSerial>.*?),
                    \ deviceDescription=(?<deviceDescription>.*)\]
              }x)
    {
            my ($productId, $cardId) = ($1, $2);
            print '"'
            . join('","',
                    $customerId,
                    $customerName,
                    $+{baseProductId},
                    $+{baseCardId},
                    $+{deviceSerial},
                    $+{deviceDescription},
                    $+{cardDescription},
               )
            . "\"\n" ;
    }
}

__DATA__
Customer [customerId=12000, customerName=Acme, Inc.]
DeviceDetail [baseProductId=router-100, cardDetail=[CardDetail [baseCardId=router-100NIC1, cardDescription=Router 100 NIC, cardSerial=100NIC1], CardDetail [baseCardId=router-100NIC2, cardDescription=Router 100 NIC, cardSerial=100NIC2]], deviceSerial=100PRIMARY, deviceDescription=Router 100 Base Model]
DeviceDetail [baseProductId=router-2500, cardDetail=[CardDetail [baseCardId=router-2500NIC1, cardDescription=Router 2500 NIC, cardSerial=2500NIC1], CardDetail [baseCardId=router-2500NIC2, cardDescription=Router 2500 NIC, cardSerial=2500NIC2]], deviceSerial=2500PRIMARY, deviceDescription=Router 2500 Base Model]
Customer [customerId=24000, customerName=Anvil LLC]
DeviceDetail [baseProductId=router-5000, cardDetail=[CardDetail [baseCardId=router-5000NIC1, cardDescription=Router 5000 NIC, cardSerial=5000NIC1], CardDetail [baseCardId=router-500NIC2, cardDescription=Router 5000 NIC, cardSerial=5000NIC2]], deviceSerial=5000PRIMARY, deviceDescription=Router 5000 Base Model]
DeviceDetail [baseProductId=router-7500, cardDetail=null, deviceSerial=7500PRIMARY, DeviceDescription=Router 7500 Base Model, No NIC]
```

You can look up the `x` option to the match `m{}` operator in `perldoc perlre` (search for the `/x` modifier. Also search for `named` capture group in the same perldoc for the `$+{foo}` incantations.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion of using something beyond awk/sed.  It appears that will have to be the route I go.  Regarding your code though; how would you force the code to place the items on the same line?  Meaning, having the Customer ID and Customer Name on each line for devices that belong to that respective customer?  The output you show has customer and devices on separate lines.  Or maybe I'm just reading it incorrectly since I see a `JOIN` clause in there.  Thanks!

Comment: You're reading it incorrectly. The lines after the ``__DATA__`` line is actually part of the code. Perl treats anything that comes after ``__DATA__`` as something that can be read from the ``DATA`` file descriptor via the ``<DATA>`` construct. To run the example code I gave you must copy the whole thing into a file, say ``t.pl`` and run ``perl t.pl``

Comment: To run the script with your input data replace ``$line = <DATA>`` with ``$line = <STDIN>`` and run the script like this: ``perl t.pl < input.txt``